# tailwindのpluginsに::-webkit-scrollbarを追加したい。

Tags: css, postcss

tailwindに独自のcssを追加出来るみたいなのですがどのように追加して良いか分からないです。下記のcssをpluginsに追加したいです。

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.no-scrollbar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

下記のconfigファイルに`::webkit`をどのように書いて良いか分からない。

```
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        '.skew-10deg': {
          transform: 'skewY(-10deg)',
        },
        '.skew-15deg': {
          transform: 'skewY(-15deg)',
        },
      }

      addUtilities(newUtilities)
    })
  ]
}
```

下記の質問を参考にしたのですが、 `::webkit` をどう書いて良いか分からなくて詰まってしまいました。
[How to create scrollable element in Tailwind without a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416614/how-to-create-scrollable-element-in-tailwind-without-a-scrollbar)

Comment: FYI: [Search · filename:{tailwind.config.js} addUtilities webkit scrollbar](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3A%7Btailwind.config.js%7D+addUtilities+webkit+scrollbar&type=Code)

Comment: FYI: [Sass: Parent Selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

Comment: ※ 回答する時間がないので、参考リンクと簡単な説明だけで失礼します。/
行いたいことと同等の処理は[Scrollbar Plugin for Tailwind CSS](https://github.com/adoxography/tailwind-scrollbar) の `.scrollbar-none` クラスで行えると思います。もし `.scrollbar-none` だけでは要件を満たせない場合は、コードも単純なため、一度当該リポジトリの `.scrollbar-none` に関連するソースコードを読んでみると良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記のサンプルコード等を参考にやってみます。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じに追加する事で上手く出来ました。

```
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = {
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      blue: {
        light: '#b9d7ea',
        DEFAULT: '#769fcd',
        dark: '#112d4e',
      },
      earth: {
        light: '#f9f7f7',
        DEFAULT: '#BDBDBD',
        dark: '#757575',
      },
      gray: {
        dark: '#212121',
        DEFAULT: '#d6e6f2',
        light: '#f7fbfc'
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        ".disable-scrollbars": {
          scrollbarWidth: "none",
          "-ms-overflow-style": "none",
          "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            width: "0px",
            background: "transparent",
            display: "none"
          },
          "& *::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            width: "0px",
            background: "transparent",
            display: "none"
          },
          "& *": {
            scrollbarWidth: "none",
            "-ms-overflow-style": "none"
          }
        }
      };
      addUtilities(newUtilities);
    })
  ],
}
```